# Draggable/Droppable - how to make drop based on mouse position (not helper center)?

Tags: jquery

When I drag a draggable, I create a helper that is a different size than the original draggable. I would like the droppables to detect entry etc. based on the mouse position. But they currently seem to be based on the **center** of the **draggable** (helper). Is there any way to make it based on the mouse position?

If not, as a second choice, is there a way to make the center of the draggable align with the mouse as soon as the drag begins? I tried this (Coffeescript) and it does not work, the mouse is positioned at its clicked point:

```
centerDragCursor = (event, ui) ->
  $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
    left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
    top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
  })

tool.draggable {
  helper: (event) -> make_new_helper_with_different_size(this)
  appendTo: '#container'
  start: centerDragCursor
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle demo of what you are refering to? I haven't had that problem with jquery before

Comment: will try to do that in a bit ... have not done that before

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the "tolerance" option on the Droppable may eventually be what you're looking for:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "pointer" });
```

see http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance